# Python file.write() to write backspace to a file

Tags: python

How can i write \b to a file using the function file.write() in python

Tried file.write('\b\b\b')   but it only adds junk characters to my file

```
 for path in data['paths']:
     file.write(path['method'] + '*')
     file.write(path['url'] + '*')
     for resources in path['resources']:
         file.write(resources['key'])
         file.write('\n'+'**')
     file.write('\b\b\b')
```

Expect to clear the last instance of ** written from the line `file.write('\n'+'**')`

Comment: A file is not the same thing as a console; you don't "erase" things in a file by adding new things (i.e. writing) to it.

Comment: Scott - can you suggest me a work around for this requirement then

Comment: to delete something in file usually you have to read all to memory, edit it and write it back. If you want to delete some chars at the end then you can use `file.truncate(new_size)` to change file's size.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write the `\n**` in the first place if you might want to delete them later.

```
 for path in data['paths']:
     file.write(path['method'] + '*')
     file.write(path['url'] + '*')
     resources = '\n**'.join(x['key'] for x in path['resources'])
     if resources:
         file.write(resources)
```

Starting with PYthon 3.8, you'll be able to combine the assignment and the `if` statement:

```
if resources := '\n**'.join(...):
    file.write(resources)
```

Comment: And if you don't know if you will need to delete them or not?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you? Looking at your code, you aren't ending each resource with a newline/`**` pair; you are putting the pair *between* each resource, and that's what the `join` does.

Comment: For this specific example, sure.

Comment: You don't *append* the characters to every element; you *prepend* the characters to the second and subsequent elements.

Comment: For this specific example, sure.